# How to start activity from UncaughtExceptionHandler if this is main thread crashed?

Tags: android, exception, unhandled-exception

I am trying to start an error-reporting activty if unhandled exception detected. The problem is with exceptions thrown from main thread. Is there any way to start an activity if main thread crashed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The approach I've seen used for error catching in an [`UncaughtExcpetionHandler`](http://d.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) is to write the crash data out to file and then start the error handling `Activity` when the application is restarted based on the existence of the crash data file.

Depending on what you want your `Activity` to do, this might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the wrong way to go about it.  What you need to do is make sure you catch those exceptions, and pop up an error-reporting activity when you catch them.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attribute `android:process=":report_process"` to the `<activity>` element which refers to your bug report activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

By default, activities belong to the same appliction would run in the same process identified by your package name.  By setting `android:process` attribute, you can override this.  `android:process` starting with `:` refers to a private identifier within your package, so that you can start the activity in a new process without conflicting other packages' process.