# Android: How to start an activity from an UncaughtExceptionHandler set in application

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, uncaught-exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start activity from UncaughtExceptionHandler if this is main thread crashed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222396/how-to-start-activity-from-uncaughtexceptionhandler-if-this-is-main-thread-crash)

My goal is to display some error messages when my Android program crashes.

I have an uncaught exception handler registered in my program's application (MyApplication) onCreate:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new HelloUncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

And when an exception is caught, I'd like to start a new activity for the user to save/submit bugs. This is what I am currently doing:

```
class HelloUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
        final Writer result = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
        e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        String stacktrace = result.toString();
        printWriter.close();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.this,
                BugReportActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("stacktrace", stacktrace);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I am getting a blank screen without BugReportActivity showing up (if I start it from an activity it works fine). The "MyApplication.this" worries me... is there really no way to launch an arbitrary activity from my application?

Thanks all.

Comment: If you want to collect the Exception data without prompting the user you could use http://www.bugsense.com or go for the ACRA plugin