# Sending e-mail from Android not working

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I just can't seem to get the e-mail sending working in Android.
Probably something stupid but I can't find it:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain")
               .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "jb@mail.anykey.co.il" })
               .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Exception in Yaniv!")
               .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"test");
    ApplicationControllerBase.getMyApplicationContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
             "Send mail...").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

I am not getting any error or exception on the startActivity command.

=======

Edit:

Seems that this is the same problem as this guy is having: [Android: How to start an activity from an UncaughtExceptionHandler set in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562277/android-how-to-start-an-activity-from-an-uncaughtexceptionhandler-set-in-applica)

Comment: You don't need the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, but other than that, it looks good to me. Are you getting an empty chooser, or is nothing showing up at all?

Answer (score 0):

setType should be `plain/text`

try with the following code

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"webmaster@website.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "mySubject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "myBodyText");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: You sure it should be plain/text? I saw the opposite elsewhere. I nevertheless tried it and nothing happened.